# PGFPlots cube* colour in legend

Tags: pgfplots

I'm using a scatter plot with `cube*` markers. All is fine with with the plot itself, however, in the legend the `cube*` appears in black. Is there a way to configure the colour used by the legend?

A small example is the following from page 133 of the PGFPlots manual (modified to use simpler standalone data instead of `plotdata/pgfplots_scatterdata4.dat`, and legend added).

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        view={120}{40},
        width=220pt,
        height=220pt,
        grid=major,
        z buffer=sort,
        xmin=-1,xmax=9,
        ymin=-1,ymax=9,
        zmin=-1,zmax=9,
        enlargelimits=upper,
        xtick={-1,1,...,19},
        ytick={-1,1,...,19},
        ztick={-1,1,...,19},
        xlabel={$l_1$},
        ylabel={$l_2$},
        zlabel={$l_3$},
        point meta={x+y+z+3},
        colormap={summap}{
            color=(black)  color=(blue)
            color=(black)  color=(white)
            color=(orange) color=(violet)
            color=(red)
        },
        scatter/use mapped color={
            draw=mapped color,fill=mapped color!70},
        ]
        \addplot3 [only marks,scatter,mark=cube*,mark size=7]
        coordinates {
              (1, 6, -1)
              (-1, -1, -1)
        };
        \addlegendentry{Test};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
\end{standalone}
```

The legend comes out black:

[image: output]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `legend image post style={mark options={...}}` to the axis options:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm, compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        view={120}{40},
        width=220pt,
        height=220pt,
        grid=major,
        z buffer=sort,
        xmin=-1,xmax=9,
        ymin=-1,ymax=9,
        zmin=-1,zmax=9,
        enlargelimits=upper,
        xtick={-1,1,...,19},
        ytick={-1,1,...,19},
        ztick={-1,1,...,19},
        xlabel={$l_1$},
        ylabel={$l_2$},
        zlabel={$l_3$},
        point meta={x+y+z+3},
        colormap={summap}{
            color=(black)  color=(blue)
            color=(black)  color=(white)
            color=(orange) color=(violet)
            color=(red)
        },
        scatter/use mapped color={
            draw=mapped color,fill=mapped color!70
        },
        legend image post style={mark options={fill=lightgray}},
        ]
        \addplot3 [only marks,scatter,mark=cube*,mark size=7]
        coordinates {
              (1, 6, -1)
              (-1, -1, -1)
        };
        \addlegendentry{Test};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

In case you want to change the size of the cube in the legend and additionally set the size of the cube edges differently, you can instead do something like the following:

```
legend image post style={
    /pgfplots/cube/size x=10pt,
    mark options={
        fill=lightgray,
        mark size=5pt,
    }
}
```

which would result in:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Is there also a way to set the cube size? `cube/size x = …` etc. seem to work neither directly inside `legend image post style` nor inside `mark options`.

Comment: (`mark size` seems to work directly inside `legend image post style` and perhaps coincidentally only affects `x` and `y` while keeping `z` at the value I have set it to, exactly as I wanted. So it solves it for me for now, but would be nice to know a way to use `cube/size`.)

Comment: @497e0bdf29873 See my edit. You need to use the full keys, for example `/pgfplots/cube/size x`.